# SQL group by using distinct column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently collecting lap times in a sql database and are having some difficulties with extracting the drivers with fastest laptimes!

The structure looks like the following!

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leaderboard` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `driver` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `car` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `best` double NOT NULL,
 `guid` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
 `server_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `track` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `driver` (`driver`),
  KEY `server_name` (`server_name`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1213 ;
```

Data example

```
INSERT INTO `leaderboard` (`id`, `driver`, `car`, `best`, `guid`, `server_name`, `track`) VALUES
(1, 'dave.38', 'bmw_m3_e30', 88.379, 76561198084629688, 'A++%21+A++%21+------+Saturdaynightracing.tk+-+%5BRACE-SERVER%5D+-+%5BMagione%5D+%23SNR', 'magione'),
(2, 'Gabriel PorfÃ­rio', 'bmw_m3_e30', 87.318, 76561197987062834, 'A++%21+A++%21+------+Saturdaynightracing.tk+-+%5BRACE-SERVER%5D+-+%5BMagione%5D+%23SNR', 'magione'),
(3, 'xX_VEGA_Xx', 'bmw_m3_e30', 88.23, 76561198182074333, 'A++%21+A++%21+------+Saturdaynightracing.tk+-+%5BRACE-SERVER%5D+-+%5BMagione%5D+%23SNR', 'magione'),
(4, 'dave.38', 'bmw_m3_e30', 88.379, 76561198084629688, 'A++%21+A++%21+------+Saturdaynightracing.tk+-+%5BRACE-SERVER%5D+-+%5BMagione%5D+%23SNR', 'magione'),
(5, 'Gabriel PorfÃ­rio', 'bmw_m3_e30', 87.318, 76561197987062834, 'A++%21+A++%21+------+Saturdaynightracing.tk+-+%5BRACE-SERVER%5D+-+%5BMagione%5D+%23SNR', 'magione');
```

Now i am trying to sort out the drivers with best time using column `best` using the following SQL but it appears as if some times are discarded, the combination of sort and order does not work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT guid, car, best, driver FROM `leaderboard` WHERE `server_name` like '%%' AND `track` = 'magione' GROUP BY(driver) ORDER BY `best` * 1 LIMIT 10
```

Please help this is driving me mad!

Comment: The entire query doesn't work correctly.  Please edit your question with the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some fields in your data are not very clear, so I made such assumptions:

- `guid` means driver's guid (because it is the same for the same driver in your data).
- `car` is the same for the same driver.

With these assumptions you can use simple `GROUP BY` to get the results that you need:

```
SELECT driver, car, MIN(best) as best_time, guid
FROM leaderboard
WHERE `server_name` like '%%' AND `track` = 'magione'
GROUP BY driver, car, guid
ORDER BY MIN(best)
```